# How to use Asp.net MVC Core with Asp.net Identity Core and WebAPi Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I am going to create an web app using Dot Net Core. In future, i will also create mobile application for the same application. Now, i am in thinking the architecture of the project. I want to use WEB API core using Asp.net Identity Core. Also, i will  consume WEB API in MVC Core application. But the question i have in mind that how i can handle ASP.net identity with MVC and WEB API? Do i need to include in MVC as well or only in WEB API?

I tried to think hard but still confuse. Need suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use token based authentication .

In a resource owner flow scenario , your client app( mvc application/native application) will consume your web api by providing user's credential , web api will validate the credential(using ASP.NET Core Identity) in database , If the username and password are correct then a JWT authentication token and the user details are returned.  Your client app could validate the token and sign in user :

[ASP.NET Core 2.2 - JWT Authentication Tutorial with Example API
Tutorial built with](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api)

[Token Authentication in ASP.NET Core 2.0 - A Complete Guide](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/03/23/token-authentication-aspnetcore-complete-guide)

In addition, [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/) is a good choice when you want to roll your own full-fledged OpenID Connect authorization server that can handle complex use cases like federation and single sign-on.

Answer (score 2):

So your question is maybe a bit open-ended for Stackoverflow and you don't really show what you have tried so far.

I will try to answer though. First you just need to start out with a template for your project. Start an MVC project in which you can easily have API endpoints as well. I would suggest splitting those in two projects for clarity - but if it is just a small personal project then you probably are fine having them in the same project. Microsoft have a pretty good resource on MVC:

[Microsoft MVC walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

For the Identity part. You would need some kind of authority for it to work. I suggest you take a look at IdentityServer4. Which offers an excellent walk-through of how to set it up and how to integrate it with Asp.NET Core Identity:

[IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/)